# jboss error due to jndi and remote sql target while starting the jboss server

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss

```
16:38:34,097 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "cdvWeb.war" of deployment "cdv.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014543: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.renault.xaf.command.RemoteSqlTargetHome' and name 'cdvEJB.jar#RemoteSqlTarget' for binding java:module/env/cdv/ejb/RemoteSqlTarget
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbInjectionSource.getResourceValue(EjbInjectionSource.java:97)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.addJndiBinding(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:229)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:120)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ... 5 more

16:38:44,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "cdv.ear" (runtime-name : "cdv.ear")
16:38:44,858 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".beanmanager (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".weld.weldClassIntrospector] 
      service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."cdv.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.subunit."cdv.ear"."cdvWeb.war".INSTALL: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase INSTALL of subdeployment "cdvWeb.war" of deployment "cdv.ear"

16:38:45,270 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
16:38:45,271 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
16:38:45,271 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.3.0.GA (AS 7.4.0.Final-redhat-19) started (with errors) in 156047ms - Started 283 of 324 services (5 services failed or missing dependencies, 73 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

i am getting this error while i am starting jboss server

please respond as soon as possible for this issue

Comment: can you please provide some details about your deployment - the application server insists that some components are not wired or coded correctly see:    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014543: No EJB found with interface of type 'com.renault.xaf.command.RemoteSqlTargetHome' and name 'cdvEJB.jar#RemoteSqlTarget' for binding java:module/env/cdv/ejb/RemoteSqlTarget

Comment: i can't get you question properly i am new to this actually so please help out in this